# Insert in MongoDB with Spring backend issue?

Tags: mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I used to insert data into a MongoDB database and i faced some problems; here is my `main.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "test";
    public static final String USERS_COLLECTION = "users";
    public static final String MONGO_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int MONGO_PORT = 27017;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        try {
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT);
            MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongo, DB_NAME);
            Test2 p = new Test2("jon");
            mongoOps.insert(p, USERS_COLLECTION);
            mongo.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}
```

Here is my entity:

```
@Document
public class Test2 extends DomainBase {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1866079511424097005L;

    private Long Id;
    private String mail;

    public Test2() {
        super();
    }

    public Test2(String mail) {
        this.setMail(mail);
    }

    @Id
    @Field("id")
    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

And here is my repository:

```
public interface Test2Repo extends MongoRepository<Test2, Long> {

}
```

I think it is well done for this part but it keep showing me the same following errors :

```
2016-03-09 15:05:02.194  INFO 19429 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/no-one/workspace/skilify-core/target/classes/, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.30/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/mobile/spring-mobile-device/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-mobile-device-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.4/jjwt-0.4.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.5.3/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.5.3/jackson-annotations-2.5.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.3/jackson-core-2.5.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.188/h2-1.4.188.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.0/commons-lang3-3.0.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.2.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar, file:/home/no-one/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar]
```

I do not know in which part or where the problem really reside, for better analysis here is the `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- Application information -->
  <groupId>**</groupId>
  <artifactId>**</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>**</name>
  <url>**</url>
  <inceptionYear>**</inceptionYear>

  <!-- Properties information -->
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.2.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.4</jjwt.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.188</h2.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    <apache-commons.version>3.0</apache-commons.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.5.201505241946</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <coveralls-maven-plugin.version>4.1.0</coveralls-maven-plugin.version>
    <jongo.version>1.1</jongo.version>
    <mongodb-driver.version>2.13.0</mongodb-driver.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- Parent information -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <!-- Dependency information -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${apache-commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>      
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>  -->

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency> 
 <!--  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>${mongodb-driver.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
    <version>${jongo.version}</version>
  </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Build information -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
        <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${coveralls-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Please could you help me ?

Comment: Can you try changing the type from Long to String for the MongoRepository? And use @Id private String id; in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I had to remove the version of the `spring-data-mongodb` dependency in the `pom.xml` to fix it since it was showing a warning; so it became :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```